# The custom UIAlertView works fine in the IOS 4.0 but it shows the default bounding box for the ios 4.2

Tags: iphone

The custom UIAlertView works fine in the IOS 4.0 but it shows the default bounding box for the ios 4.2 .Do anybody know why this happens for my customised alertview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've customized a UIAlertView by traversing the private view hierarchy and altering elements there, there is no guarantee that your code will work correctly between OS updates.  This is exactly why Apple tells you not to do this.

If you need to have something that looks like a UIAlertView, but has your own custom controls, I drew a replica of this view using Quartz in a sample application [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/QuartzExamples.zip).

Comment: I found this is the only way to overcome this problem.